# how to extend range of wireless PC headset/mic with multiple access points

Tags: wireless-networking, speech-recognition

I want to enable multiple users to walk through a warehouse and use a wireless headset/mic to communicate with their desktop PC's, using speech-recognition and text-to-speech integration, in order to input data into a desktop MS Access form. Each desktop PC would be on a network. The warehouse has metal shelving and the user might be up to a few hundred feet away from his PC.   Please advise me on the required  hardware and procedure in order to accomplish my objective and let me know if you have any additional insight on the matter.
Thank you very much in advance, Nathaniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a wireless repeater.

[image]

All you do is connect the repeaters to the original wireless network or using a Ethernet Cable.

[Price Range Here](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/Networking/Wireless-Network-Extenders/pcmcat161100050044.c?id=pcmcat161100050044)

Comment: please outline how the wireless headset/microphone gets set up with the repeaters, to enable back and forth communication with the desktop  PC. I have not yet purchased the headset. I think that the headset communicates with a USB transmitter/receiver.  My purpose is to extend the range of the headset.

Comment: Can you send me a link to the headsets you are looking to buy? Ive seen wireless headset and microphones that just use Wifi.If there is a USB transmitter, lets see what technology it uses to transmit the data.

Comment: http://salestores.com/gnnetcomjabr.html